# Array to string conversion while create data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i got this error while created data and retrieve to my view

> Array to string conversion

this my code controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validate = $request->validate([
      'active' => '',
      'cancel' => '',
      'finish' => ''
    ]);
 
    StatusProject::create($validate);
    return redirect('/statusproject')->with('success','Success Create Status Project!');
}
```

and this is my view

```
 @foreach ($data as $item)
        <th scope="row">{{ $loop->iteration }}</th>
        <td>{{ $item->active }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->cancel }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->finish }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

can someone explain to me what happen on this error

Comment: Which line of code throws the error? Presumably, one of the items you're trying to show on the screen is an array, instead of text - that's what the error means.

Comment: no error show in code but if i submit the data laravel show notice "Array to string conversion"

Comment: The error message should always give you a line number and a filename

Comment: @ADyson this is the error show https://flareapp.io/share/KPgXWVZ7#F64

Comment: What are your request inputs?

Comment: @A.Seddighi my request input is integer, when i change code to query builder its work to create data and show data in view but while delete data with query builder or eloquent it say Array to string conversion . error just show in laravel debug not even in vscode errors showing

Comment: Why you are your validations are empty strings?

Comment: i change validation to nullable and numeric . but still not work